# Calling a JSP application from current JSP application

Tags: jsp

Is there a way I can call/embedd another jsp application within my current application?
As in, say in my application I have some content and at a particular place I would like to show another application. 
I will not be able to include the `include` directive, because the other jsp page is in another application..
Is this possible? if so, would anyone be able to tell me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only include its HTML output by JSTL `<c:import>`.

```
<c:import url="http://other.com/page.jsp" />
```

You only need to ensure that it ends in [valid](http://validator.w3.org/) HTML. I.e. no nested `<html><html>` tags. If you have no control over its output, then using a HTML `<iframe>` is your best bet.

```
<iframe src="http://other.com/page.jsp"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iFrame to call the JSP in the other application.  Some caveats are involved, however.

1: You will get a new session when you call the second application's code.  This means that any saved data in your session will be gone.

2: You will need to account for an interesting case if you need session handling in both applications. If the parent session has expired but the child session is still active, you will need to track this case.

3: If authorization or authentication is involved, you will need to synchronize across Application Contexts.

```
<iframe src="second/application/included.jsp" />
```

will include the code in the parent application.